# Unrecognized VM option 'UseCompressedStrings' - Intellij IDEA doesn't lauch

Tags: java, ubuntu, intellij-idea, jvm

I added the `UseCompressedStrings` VM option via IDEA and shut it down. Now when I tried to launch IDEA again it wouldn't launch. I got the following error:

```
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: Option UseConcMarkSweepGC was deprecated in version 9.0 and will likely be removed in a future release.
Unrecognized VM option 'UseCompressedStrings'
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
```

I checked the `idea64.vmoptions` and `idea.vmoptions` to remove this unrecognized flag but the `UseCompressedStrings` flag wasn't there. I didn't know how to resolve the issue from there so I uninstalled and re-installed both IDEA and java hoping that the error will go away but the error still persists. Note that I had increased the heap size as well in the 64vmoptions file and that was gone too. Can anyone advise on how to resolve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I ended up doing a global search in my ubuntu like this:

```
grep ~ -rnw -e "UseCompressedStrings"
```

found out that the configs are backed up in:

```
/home/{username}/.config/JetBrains/IntelliJIdea2020.1/idea64.vmoptions
```

Which is why despite reinstalling java and intellij this invalid option was still visible to the jvm. So I removed the line there and things worked fine.

Comment: For me it was just the same but removing `-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC`.

Answer (score 0):

`UseCompressedStrings` is a feature that was deprecated a long time ago, and removed in Java 7. It is not a valid VM option in modern JVMs.

Since Java 9, there is a [similar feature called "compact strings"](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/254) and it is enabled by default. Like "UseCompressedStrings" this feature uses a byte array to store strings when it's possible. You can read more details about "compact strings" and how it compares with "compressed strings" in [this article](https://www.baeldung.com/java-9-compact-string).

Answer (score 0):

Common solutions to such problems(Ubuntu):

1. Find the path /home/$USER/.config/JetBrains/IntelliJIdea2021.1
2. Remove the deprecated configuration of JVM prameters.
3. Restart intelliJiIdea